# Does the blessing "Poke'ach 'Ivrim" contain an allusion to the ill effects of bribery?

Tags: blessing, prayer-book, beit-din-court, see-sight-vision-blind, mishpatim

[One](http://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz,_Weekday,_Shacharit,_Preparatory_Prayers,_Morning_Blessings.5?lang=bi) of the [Blessings of the Morning](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Birchot_HaShachar) says that God

> פּוֹקֵחַ עִוְרִים
>
> opens [the eyes of] the blind

<sup>(Sefaria community translation)</sup>

This phrase is an almost exact reversal of the Torah's description ([Exodus 23:8](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.23.8?lang=bi)) of what bribery does:

> וְשֹׁ֖חַד לֹ֣א תִקָּ֑ח כִּ֤י הַשֹּׁ֙חַד֙ **יְעַוֵּ֣ר פִּקְחִ֔ים** וִֽיסַלֵּ֖ף דִּבְרֵ֥י צַדִּיקִֽים׃
>
> Do not take bribes, for bribes **blind the clear-sighted** and upset the pleas of those who are in the right.

<sup>(JPS 1985 translation, from Sefaria)</sup>

Clearly, whoever composed this blessing was well aware of this verse, so I'm wondering if the allusion was intentional, and if so, what the intent is. It would seem that the plain meaning of the blessing refers literally to visual blindness, while the verse refers figuratively to the muddling of clear reasoning. Despite that, is what we're thanking God for every morning supposed to be either a remedy for bribery or something that bribery undermines?

Do any commentaries on the Siddur explain a relationship between this blessing and this verse?

Comment: The text of this and another bracha reflect Tehillim 146:8 which, in Yoma 35b seems to be taken literally. Thought medrash Tehillim ads another dimension ומי הן העורים הדורות האלו שהולכות בתורה כעורים.

Comment: Is the phrase really that unique to that verse that we should assume an intended allusion?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm asking, not assuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source for this morning blessing is clearly from [Tehillim 146:8](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Tehillim/146.8#e0n7) (which we say every morning in Pesukei Dezimra), and thus, it is highly unlikely that this language was chosen so to allude to Shemos 23:8.

I did not see any Mefarshim  to Tehillim 146:8 (I checked Mikraos Gedolos and other sources) make a connection to Shemos 23:8 (which makes sense, as either of these words appear many times throughout Tanach). However, Malbim says that this includes giving Tzaddikim Sechel, as well as blessing them with literal "sight".

I would also note that the previous Passuk discusses Hashem's judgment, so perhaps this is a Chiddush in the making.

Comment: Thanks for digging this up and for the closing encouragement! Now I know what I'm going to be taking a close look at over Shabbat.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Thanks, let me know what you come up with!

Comment: I have to go through the Concordantzia entries carefully to be sure, but at a glance, it looks like the pairing of these two roots (in noun or verb form) is present in only a handful of pesukim throughout Tanach.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I meant unpaired ("either of these words").  But, see Yeshaya 35:5, 42:7 for two paired pesukim (and sort of paired - Shemos 4:11)